# unit-test in eclipse cdt

Tags: c++, unit-testing, eclipse-cdt

In eclipse cdt when I use the new class wizard, it asks if I want to add a unit test file, but I am not sure how to use that file, it does not follow any unit test framework. Am I supposed to just use it to write a main and execute it, or should I just ignore it and use a framework?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure and you **want** to write **unit tests**, better use a dedicated framework. Eg. [CppUTest](http://cpputest.github.io/) is great here - and integrates well with eclipse (scroll down to *"Related projects"*).

If you need just some basic unit tests you may use the one from eclipse.